# Significance of Compiling CUDA in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, deep-learning, cuda

I want to construct a deep learning platform in Windows(Windows10+CUDA10+VS2019).

In the tutorial of some blogs, some bloggers suggested to compile the CUDA (sample) after install the Nvidia GPU Computing toolkit. I don't really understand this action.

In my experiment, I found that the computing speed of training the network has been improved, without compiling the CUDA in VS2019. Then what is the significance of compiling CUDA in windows(VS)? Just to confirm if CUDA is installed successfully?

Thank you in advance for your help. I don't know much about c++. Maybe this question is very naive for you.

Comment: Whether GPU processing is going to benefit your algorithm or not depends on *many* factors.

Answer (score 2):

You do not compile the CUDA libraries themselves - those are distributed in binary form.

The CUDA toolkit installer contains many sample programs for different features and use-cases of CUDA. It is not a bad idea to compile them - but not because you need to do so for your own deep learning work: It will simply ensure that...

- CUDA is properly installed and configured
- Your GPU is properly installed
- You have a valid driver installed, compatible with your version of CUDA

and it's better to do so with code that's known to build and run correctly elsewhere than with whatever you're working on getting to work.